# Get rid of [retry]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

I don't find any value in having [retry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/retry), and I think you feel the same.

Comment: Let's burn retry-policy too!

Comment: Ah, but shouldn't we *all* be experts in retrying?

Comment: If people don't like this idea, you could always post it again in a few days with a [tag:retry] tag. It would give the tag a whole new meaning. ;)

Comment: If at first you don't succeed...

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I agree. Any expert in *retrying*? No. Question can't be clarified by [retry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/retry), this tag says nothing. It seems unlikely that anyone will search questions tagged by [retry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/retry) to answer them. It has 73 questions and only 1 follower.

Comment: One follower? So that's not nobody!

Comment: @MrLister: I always wanted to have the bunination process more formalized in that followers get notified so they can explain why they do so, maybe that gives some insight (e.g. here I would think if retry is maybe a language keyword somewheree)

Comment: I like this style of answer.

Answer (score 21):

No [retry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/retry) questions left :-)